# css alignment in a page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align "Discuss" "Bury" with the above text in the site but in vain
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/story.php?title=latest-headling-mews-gossip-fun-entertainment-music-gala-and-so-on-for-you-only-for-the-purpose-of-entertaining-you

see the screenshot

[image]

I want to align just as in the screenshot

how this can be achieved ?

Comment: What does your code look like right now? What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Dude It is very simple but will you paste your code so you will get your modified code not a new code

Comment: have you tried margin-left:#px; ?

Comment: Where's the problem? When I look at the site you provided, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Remove the left padding from `.storycontent1`:

```
.storycontent1
{
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Then add the padding to `.storycontent`

```
.storycontent
{
    padding-left:80px;
}
```

**Option 2**

Add this style rule:

```
#linksummaryDiscuss {
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

This option will only work if the `Discuss` span is always there.

Comment: Your option 2 works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You need to move that span.linksummaryDiscuss into div with storycontent1 class

or just wrap it in a div and style it (somewhat simliar to div.storycontent1)

```
.newdiv {
    padding: 0 80px;
    width: 580px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move the style: `padding: 0 80px;` from `.storycontent1` selector to `.storycontent`.